# How much does adventuring gear made for very small and very large creatures weigh and cost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, creature-size, pricing

I'm trying to make a full chart of item sizes and I find something is lacking in the Player's Handbook (or I'm just blind). See the following chart:

[image: Item size chart]

(Excel file [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3826B0051680039C!7656&authkey=!ADzbxz-YnBmHRm8&ithint=file%2Cxlsx))

How much does special-sized adventuring gear weigh and cost? I would like to complete the question marks in the table.

Comment: Would like to get an updated link to download the excel file. It appears to no longer be active on onedrive.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I have no idea where that file went. I think I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple (official to my knowledge) answer.

When magic is involved the cost is given by the magic enhancement irregardless of size. As money quickly goes into the tens of thousands, few care about tiny sized weapons base cost instead paying full price and saving time on the paperwork shortcut.

However, there are some suggestions:

- DMG has section about modifying equipment for abnormal body types, such as wings or extra arms. Its 30% more base cost. Considering the difficulty in making tiny rivets and stitching...
- Model the solution off of armor: Tiny, Fine, & Diminutive = 1/2 x Small. Large x 8 = Huge x 4 = Gargantuan x 2 = Colossal (doubles each size increment). The larger options being for material costs, while smaller requires crafting skill regardless of material savings.
- Outside of weapons: magic items (like rings) adjust to user size and have the same cost and weight. Personal items (like tents, food, water skins) adjust by 3/4th per size increment by Player Hand Book. Some items (like tools, vials, books, and rope) have a fixed cost regardless of character size, by logic and player hand book. [Huge troll climbing thin silk rope, maybe house rule that?]
- In general, the answer is always ask the DM, house rules abound. Some campaigns ignore weight in all but extreme cases. [Carrying a castle or 100 weapons.]

Comment: It would be nice if your answer delved more into weight. Also, I think there's a mistake in your second bullet point. I don't understand at all your list of multiplicators. Seems to suggest Large equipment is more expensive than Colossal equipment, which is puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

Player's Handbook (pg114) states "This cost is the same for a Small or Medium version of the weapon. A Large version costs twice the listed price." It could then be extrapolated that the costs for sizes larger than Large would double the price again for every size category up you go. It could also be extrapolated that sizes smaller than Small have the cost halved for each size category down you go.

As for weight, Player's Handbook (pg114) states "Halve this number for Small weapons, and double it for Large weapons." Again you can extrapolate this by either doubling or halving the weight for every size category you go up or down (respectively).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. You might also be interested in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129024/8610) that covers the costs and weights of weapons. This question, however, is about adventuring gear broadly, so it's hard to say if or how the rules for unusually sized weapons (which, to be clear, are different from the similar rules for unusually sized armor) might apply to, for example, thieves' tools or a saddle. No matter what, though, thank you for participating and have fun!