# Are there official full stats for a Titan's Great Warhammer?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, dnd-3e

The [Titan](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/titan.htm) entry in the *Monster Manual* or SRD mentions that Titans use a "great two-handed warhammer" which is a gargantuan weapon that does 4d6 damage.

Are there actual official 'rest of the stats' for this weapon (weight, cost, etc) anywhere, or failing that, is there a way I could calculate what the stats should be within the context of existing official rules material, such as a medium great warhammer from some source book that could be scaled up using the weapons for differently sized creatures rules?

Comment: The only thing I could find of weapons larger than Large and smaller than Small was in the Arms and Equipment Guide that is 3.0 material (and I don't agree with their costs and weight). Since it isn't 3.5, I'm not answering your question but I'm leaving the source here in case you're interested.

Comment: By default, the 3.5 tag on SE includes all non updated 3.0 material? So please post your answer. Just in case, I've added the 3.0 tag.

Answer (score 4):

Prices and weights for *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* weapons bigger than Large and littler than Small are in the *Rules Compendium*. On Weapon Qualities on Cost says

> This value is the weapon’s cost in coins. The cost includes all miscellaneous gear that goes with the weapon, such as a sheath. This cost is the same for a Small or Medium version of the weapon. A larger version costs twice the noted price per size category larger than Medium. A smaller version costs half the price per two size categories smaller than Medium (round up). (151)

And on Weight says

> This is the weight of a Medium version of the weapon. A larger version weighs twice as much per size category larger than Medium. A smaller version weighs half as much per size category smaller than Medium. (*ibid.*)

This is—sadly—completely different from, for example, the *Player's Handbook* chart [Armor for Unusual Creatures](http://dndsrd.net/armor.html#armor-for-unusual-creatures) (123). (I used that chart to scale weapons using the Humanoid cost and weight columns before discovering this information buried in the *Rules Compendium*.)

Thus, after this DM's PCs defeat a typical [titan](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#titan) (*Monster Manual* 242–3), they'll find that titan's *+3 [adamantine](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#adamantine) Gargantuan warhammer* has a cost of 21,096 gp and a weight of 40 lbs. (That is, it's 8× the cost and weight of a normal warhammer due to the *Rules Compendium*'s rules and an additional +3,000 gp for the special material adamantine (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 283)—but see below—, and +18,000 gp for [the magical +3 enhancement bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#table-weapons) (222). Note that the cost of the warhammer's masterwork quality is subsumed in the cost of the special material adamantine.)

#### Do special materials' flat costs and weight adjustments scale?

So far as I can tell, the rules are silent on whether to scale the price and weight modifications due to special materials with a flat cost when those special material are applied to weapons. ([For what it's worth](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610), the *D&D Main FAQ* addresses this obliquely for armor on page 50 yet makes no mention of how or if to do the same with weapons.)

So you know, this DM does *not* scale special materials' costs and weights: this DM believes such scaling unfairly rewards the little and punishes the big, and leads to every big creature (and some little creatures, too, depending on the special material) buying a Fine magic weapon made of a special material and adding to that weapon the magic weapon special ability ***sizing*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 43) (5,000 gp; 0 lbs.), bypassing most exorbitant costs a big weapon would normally incur anyway. It may not be particularly (*ahem*) realistic to have Fine weapons cost the same to be made adamantine as Colossal weapons, but it makes this DM feel better to charge everybody that flat +3,000 gp rather than charging for an adamantine Fine dagger +750 gp and for a Colossal adamantine dagger +48,000 gp.

Also note that this DM also rarely uses areas of [antimagic](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#antimagic)—which would temporarily negate the magic weapon special ability *sizing*—, so in campaigns where antimagic is more common, scaling the cost and weight adjustments for special materials and adding the magic weapon special ability *sizing* is a calculated risk that may sometimes leave a wielder with a favorite weapon bought on the cheap that's not as useful as the wielder would like.

Comment: Rules Compendium? Damn, I lent my copy to a friend and couldn't verify it. To think it was in the only book I don't have in my possession at the moment. -_-'

Answer (score 2):

Being a bladesmith by trade as well as a D&D DM I would like to throw in something manuals never consider in remotely a realistic way.

increasing the volume (size) of something exponentially increases the weight.

As an example, if we assume adamantine weighs the same as steel, then a normal warhammer head would weigh around 5-6 lbs. However if we attempt to increase this to giant size...

A block of steel that is one foot in length, breadth and thickness (still notably too small for a titan, this would be about the size of its thumb) would weigh 490 lbs.

As a rule of thumb for this kind of thing I take the creature weight (a titan is 14000 pounds according to the manual) and scale the weapon by weight accordingly.

Assuming an average human weighs around 200 lbs, and a warhammer that is comfortable for it weighs 5 pounds, it is 1/40th the weight of the humanoid wielder.

Thus a titan sized warhammer would weigh 1/40 of a titan's weight. Which is 350 lbs.

That's the best scaling system I've been able to come up with

Comment: Oh! Nice pull from real life experience. I like this observation.

Answer (score 0):

### There are rules in 3.0 for every size but weapon size rules were a bit different back then.

Arms and Equipment Guide pg. 4 says:

> **Size, Weight and Price:** If you're designing a weapon larger than the standard, its weight increases by 50% for each size category increase. Its cost increase at the same rate. So if you design a Large version of a throwing axe (ordinarily a Small weapon weighting 4 pounds) it will weigh 9 pounds: A Medium-size weighs 6 pounds, and a Large version increase the weight by a further 50%. Its costs increases by the same amount, so a Large throwing axe would cost 18gp.
>   Weight decreases by 25% per size category decrease if you're designing a smaller version of a weapon. A throwing axe weighs only 3 pounds if you make a Tiny version of it. Costs also decrease by 25% per size category decrease, so a Tiny throwing axe would cost only 6gp.

In 3.0, weapons have their own size and not sized for the creature, the reason why there were no halfling-sized greataxes around or Ogre-sized daggers. A halfling would use a longsword as a two-handed weapon and the Ogre would use a shortsword as a dagger.

### There are no official rules in 3.5 for weapons smaller than Small or larger than Large.

There is common house-rule around of doubling the cost and weight of weapons for each size category increase over medium and half the weight and cost for each size category smaller than Small (Remembering that Small weapons, while having half the weight have the same cost as their Medium counterparts).

While the creatures weight increases by a factor of 8 for each size increase (the correct factor by physics), they use doublings for equipment from Small to Medium and Medium to Large. The cost is a bit tricky because of the same price of Small and Medium. I suggest using the house-rule I mentioned for 3.5 than the 3.0 rules.

Going by extrapolation from the book it would be:

- 3012 gp, 5lb for a Medium-sized nonmagical adamantine warhammer (1d8).
- 6024 gp, 10lb for a Large-sized nonmagical adamantine warhammer (2d6).
- 12048 gp, 20lb for a Huge-sized nonmagical adamantine warhammer (3d6).
- 24096 gp, 40lb for a Gargantuan-sized nonmagical adamantine warhammer (4d6).
- 42096 gp, 40lb for a Gargantuan-sized +3 adamantine warhammer (4d6+3).

Comment: Adamantine weapons are +1 to hit. due to hardness and masterwork not magic http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialMaterials.htm#adamantine

Comment: @ravery Yes, the +1 to hit part was ignored since it isn't relevant here. I got the cost of a nonmagical Medium-sized weapon made of adamantine and doubled for every size increase until Gargantuan size. Magical enhancement costs were added last.

Comment: how is a property of adamantine irrelevant? the damage done (as listed) is 4d6 + 1 1/2 time strength .... as far as I can tell

Comment: @ravery Well, we were talking about size, cost, weight and damage. The to hit part was not relevant info for the purpose of this question. The question isn't about adamantine properties or how to add Strength modifier to weapon damage.

Comment: hmmm, perhaps there is a magic bonus in there too. the numbers work both ways....

Comment: Actually, I think there are Wesson sizes in 3.5. It's an offhand reference though: SRD mentions that a light weapon is two size categories smaller than the character it is sized for, a one handed is one size smaller, and a two-handed weapon is the same size category. Which makes claws or fists amusing, and yields a possible approach to a solution with grappling.

Comment: @nijineko In the SRD, their example is a bit weird. It is correct though if you're talking about a two-handed weapon (greatsword, falchion etc). Even so, no rules about weight or cost.

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.5 has no rules for cost and weight of weapons beyond small-large, we have to fall back to 3.0.

(3.0) Arms and Equipment Guide pg. 4 says:

> Size, Weight and Price: If you're designing a weapon larger than the standard, its weight increases by 50% for each size category increase. Its cost increases at the same rate.

The [Titan's](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/titan.htm) warhammer is [adamantine](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialMaterials.htm#adamantine), which makes the cost +3000 gp.

It is also a +3 [magic weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm), which adds another +18000 gp.

I will assume that, as adamantine is a physical property, it is multiplied by the sizing modifier, but magical enhancement doesn't care about the size, so will be applied after.

An ordinary (Medium) [warhammer](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#martialWeapons) costs 12 gp, and weighs 5 lbs.
Make it adamantine, total price 3012 gp.

Sizing it up, +50% each step:
Large = 4518 gp, 7.5 lbs.
Huge = 6777 gp, 11.25 lbs.
Gargantuan = 10165.5 gp, 16.875 lbs

Add the +3 [magic weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm) cost, +18000 gp.

That gives us a **total cost of 28165 gp + 5 sp**, and a **weight of 17 lbs** (rounded up).
*This seems **very** light for such a big weapon, but that's what the (3.0) RAW says.*

---

Damage is as listed in the Titan's stats, after taking strength into account: 4d6+3/x3
*(he has a +16 str mod, and is using it 2-handed, so gets x1.5 bonus = 24)*

Comment: I'm still not sure if the +3 is a magic bonus or an adamantine masterwork bonus.

Comment: The +1 to-hit included with Adamantine is because it must be Masterwork. There's no such thing as master-master-masterwork. And it clearly says that it is a +3 weapon.

Comment: well, I guess you're right, but I can see +3 due to shear size (40 lbs. if doubling)

Comment: One challenge with this answer is that a warhammer is a one handed weapon, while a Titan's Great Warhammer is a two-handed weapon, and is thus a full size category bigger. (See weapon size in the SRD ). I like the calculations, though.

Comment: It has the expected damage of a regular 1-handed warhammer of that size. With the added strength bonus of using it two handed.

Comment: @nijineko  The warhammer is two-handed for the titan because it is a Gargantuan weapon being wielded by a Huge creature.  You will notice in the stat block it is only listed as Gargantuan _+3 adamantine warhammer_.  In the _PHB_, in the section on _Inappropriately Sized Weapons_, it indicates that a one-handed weapon becomes a two-handed weapon when wielded by a creature one size category smaller than it was designed for.  The titan's Oversized Weapon ability removes the penalty, but not the need to use two hands.

Comment: As far as cost and weight goes, in 3.5 both are consistently doubled in transitioning from Small to Medium and from Medium to Large, so I would say it is safe to say that that is the new standard and go with that, resulting in 20,096 (+18,000 gp for enchantment, so 38,096 total) gp cost and 40# weight.